# Можно ли открывать файлы напрямую через ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Можно ли открывать файлы напрямую через ListBox? Нужно например: если нажать в ListBox вторую строку и тогда, чтоб открылся в программе файл "Scene2" без вызова диалогового окна. И тотже пример, если  нажать в ListBox десятую строку и чтоб открылся файл "Scene10" по определенному пути.

Код кнопки "Open", который открывает файлы через диалоговое окно вот так выглядит:

```
private void buttonOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Title = "Open only NAMEMENU.MNU";
        ofd.Filter = "All files|*.*";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filename = ofd.FileName;
            buttonSave.Enabled = true;

            buf = File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName);

            foreach (UserControlHeros item in HeroPanel.Controls)
            {
                if (item.selected)
                {
                    userControlHeros_Click(item, null);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Нужно также открывать файл как в коде выше, только без диалогового окна, через ListBox.

Comment: Ну, если вы знаете имя файла, то диалог не нужен, разумеется. Но вы должны знать имя файла.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что вопрос заключается в том, как в событии DoubleClick или Click получить элемент списка находящийся под курсором, и его значение (имя файла)? Если да, поправьте, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (удалив ненужные детали, и добавив нужные).

Comment: Вопрос в том, чтоб в событии Click по строке из списка ListBox открыть файл в буфере программы, то есть считать байты с определенного файла. А каждая строка(элемент) в списке ListBox будет соответствовать такому-то файлу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void buttonOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string filepath = "Scene" + listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString(); // Где listBox1 имя вашего listBox
            buf = File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Отличный метод, спасибо. То что и было нужно. Правда, интересно как метод узнает путь к файлу?

Answer (score 0):

Замените получение имени файла из диалогового окна на его взятие из выбранного в данный момент элемента ListBox.

Answer (score 0):

По методу выше от Иван Стоцкий. Подходящий ответ такой:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string filepath = "scene" + (listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1).ToString();

            filename = filepath;
            labelFileSaved.Text = Path.GetFileName(filepath);

            buf = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);

            foreach (UserControlHeros item in HeroPanel.Controls)
            {
                if (item.selected)
                {
                    userControlHeros_Click(item, null);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```